# Struts Nested Tag with Dynamic Parameters

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I have a legacy Struts 1 application which uses the nested tag. Can I inject a dynamic parameter into the nested tag? For example,

```
<nested:select disabled="<c:out value='${requestScope.disableSelectBox}' />" />
```

I also tried doing:

```
<nested:select disabled="${requestScope.disableSelectBox}" />
```

In both of the above examples, the disabled attribute was not properly set and it was ignored. If I printout the value with a c:out, the correct value of disableSelectBox is displayed:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.disableSelectBox}" />
```

A colleague suggested that I should use:

```
<nested:select disabled="<%=request.getAttribute("disableSelectBox"); %>" />
```

The trouble is that it is considered bad practice to use java scriplets in a JSP page. Is there any way to embed a dynamic variable into a Struts 1 nested tag? Switching to Struts 2 is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't do Struts, so I may be wrong, but if that scriptlet solution worked, then option 2 should in theory have worked as well if you're using at least JSP 2.0 (i.e. the web.xml is declared conform at least Servlet version 2.4 and you're running the webapp on a Servlet 2.4 compatible server).

Answer (score 1):

Struts 1 (as far as I can remember) cannot allow you to do:

```
<nested:select disabled="<c:out value='${requestScope.disableSelectBox}' />" />
```

As it can't process JSP tags inside any of their attribute declarations, Check what `nested:select disabled` attribute **required** needs.

But Struts do support EL and JSP Scriplets (so your colleague is correct). JSP Scriptlet will "render" the value of the `<%=request.getAttribute("disableSelectBox"); %>` and assign it to the `<nested:select disabled="<%=request.getAttribute("disableSelectBox"); %>" />`

So (if I assume that the values returns a true or false,

```
<nested:select disabled="${requestScope.disableSelectBox}" />
```

and

```
<nested:select disabled="<%=request.getAttribute("disableSelectBox"); %>" />
```

will be rendered as (if results returns true)

```
<nested:select disabled="true" />
```

before it is sent to Struts to render the nested tag (sorry for using the word "render", you can use translate if you want).